# jQuery queue does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

Let multiple cards in the queue slide in after each other on document ready and for the elements that arent visible on page load I want the same for them on scroll.

**The problem:**

All elements slide in at the same time. (Even though I'm using an each loop)

**Example:**

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
    readyAnimation("slide-in-left");
    readyAnimation("slide-in-cards");
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    readyAnimation("slide-in-left");
    readyAnimation("slide-in-cards");
});

function readyAnimation (animationClass) {

var resetAnimationClass = "reset-animations";

$("." + animationClass).each(function() {

    var elem = $(this);

    if(elem.hasClass(animationClass)) {

        if (isScrolledIntoView(elem) == true ) {
               elem.delay(500).queue(function(){
                elem.addClass(resetAnimationClass).dequeue();
           })
        } 
      }
    });
 }

function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return (docViewBottom >= elemTop && docViewTop <= elemBottom);
}
```

```css
.card {
  float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: $brand;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: #333;
}

.slide-in-cards {
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.61, 0.56, 1), opacity 600ms cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
    will-change: transform;
}

.reset-animations {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
        <img />
   </div>
   <div class="card slide-in-cards">
        <img />
   </div>
   <div class="card slide-in-cards">
         <img />
   </div>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
        <img />
   </div>
   <div class="card slide-in-cards">
        <img />
   </div>
   <div class="card slide-in-cards">
         <img />
   </div>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
        <img />
   </div>
   <div class="card slide-in-cards">
        <img />
   </div>
   <div class="card slide-in-cards">
         <img />
   </div>
   ...
```

**What I did so far:**

My markup looks like this:

```
   <div class="card slide-in-cards">
        <img />
   </div>
   <div class="card slide-in-cards">
        <img />
   </div>
   <div class="card slide-in-cards">
         <img />
   </div>
   ...
```

And I want them so slide in after each other by using something like this:

```
function readyAnimation (animationClass) {

var resetAnimationClass = "reset-animations";

$("." + animationClass).each(function() {

    var elem = $(this);

    if(elem.hasClass(animationClass)) {

        if (isScrolledIntoView(elem) == true ) {
               elem.delay(500).queue(function(){
                elem.addClass(resetAnimationClass).dequeue();
           })
        } 
      }
    });
 }
```

I add a class that resets their css to normal, the elements have the transition property

This function is called like this

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    readyAnimation("slide-in-left");
    readyAnimation("slide-in-cards");
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    readyAnimation("slide-in-left");
    readyAnimation("slide-in-cards");
});
```

The isScrolledIntoView function is from stackoverflow and looks like this

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return (docViewBottom >= elemTop && docViewTop <= elemBottom);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. Remember that animations on separate elements run in *parallel*; each element has its own animation queues.
2. You've said that you had an issue when more elements come into view. That's because you weren't eliminating them from the selection of elements to animate.
3. Your `if (elem.hasClass(animationClass))` check is unnecessary, as you've selected only elements that have that class.

So (see `***` commented lines):

```
function readyAnimation(animationClass) {

  var resetAnimationClass = "reset-animations";

  var counter = 0;                                                          // ***
  $("." + animationClass).not("." + resetAnimationClass).each(function() {  // ***

    var elem = $(this);

    // *** No `if (elem.hasClass(animationClass))` here, we know it does
    if (isScrolledIntoView(elem) == true) {
      ++counter;                                                            // ***
      elem.delay(500 * counter).queue(function() {                          // ***
        elem.addClass(resetAnimationClass).dequeue();
      })
    }
  });
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //readyAnimation("slide-in-left");
  readyAnimation("slide-in-cards");
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  //readyAnimation("slide-in-left");
  readyAnimation("slide-in-cards");
});

function readyAnimation(animationClass) {

  var resetAnimationClass = "reset-animations";

  var counter = 0;
  $("." + animationClass).not("." + resetAnimationClass).each(function() {

    var elem = $(this);

    if (isScrolledIntoView(elem) == true) {
      ++counter;
      elem.delay(500 * counter).queue(function() {
        elem.addClass(resetAnimationClass).dequeue();
      })
    }
  });
}

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return (docViewBottom >= elemTop && docViewTop <= elemBottom);
}
```

```css
.card {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background: $brand;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #333;
}
.slide-in-cards {
  transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.61, 0.56, 1), opacity 600ms cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
  will-change: transform;
}
.reset-animations {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
  <img />
</div>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
  <img />
</div>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
  <img />
</div>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
  <img />
</div>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
  <img />
</div>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
  <img />
</div>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
  <img />
</div>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
  <img />
</div>
<div class="card slide-in-cards">
  <img />
</div>
...
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. I've tried that already, sadly that solution doesn't work because, as you scroll down, the elements have a very long delay. That was actually my first approach to this but I couldn't get the counter to reduce properly.

Comment: @JanCastle: That's because you weren't eliminating the already-animated ones from the selection. I've updated above to handle that.

Comment: Wow thanks! The new .not function works very well. I've accepted your answer. If I may ask, do you know a way to improve the perfomance of this code? I'd like to make it as optimized as possible.

Comment: @JanCastle: Actually, you could also do this: `$("." + animationClass + ":not(." + resetAnimationClass + ")").each(...` because `:not` with a simple selector (like a class selector) is supported by all major browsers now. It's a premature micro-optimization, but hey. :-)

Comment: Oh yeah that's awesome! A last question if I may :)

My way to call the functions, 4 times. Is that optimizable?

Comment: @JanCastle: If you want the animations for the "left" vs. "cards" ones to be independent, calling `readyAnimation` twice seems reasonable. I would move both calls to a named function, and then call that function from `ready` and `scroll`.

Comment: Allright, Thank you very much for your time. I really appreciate it.